# Clang++ Fails To Detect Use of Uninitialized Member Variable

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

Using clang++ version 11 and C++ 17 with the compiler flag `-Wall`, clang will normally complain if you use a variable before it is initialized. However, it does not detect the following case:

```
struct Bar
{
  bool b1;
};

class Foo {
public:
  Foo()
    : b2(Bar{b2}.b1) // We are using b2 here before it is initialized, but clang doesn't complain
  { }

  bool b2;
};
```

This is the simplest example that I can create. It seems to only happen when initializing a member variable in the constructor (b2 in this case) with a member variable (b1) of an object (Bar). Does anyone know why clang fails to detect the problem here?

I recognize that this is a contrived example, but it actually caused a problem for me and I'd like to understand it.

Comment: Looks like a Clang bug to me, consider reporting it.

Comment: No C++ compiler is required to figure out that an uninitialized variable is used in every possible situation where that may happen. Any time your compiler is smart enough to do so, it's just as extra bonus.

Comment: ... reporting it is really is the most meaningful thing one can do.

Comment: `gcc` and `icc` also don't complain. Neither does `cl`.

Comment: Finding all unused uses would essentially be the halting problem, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to detect if you used a member variable before it is initialized in the general case.  Doing so for general programs violates Rice's theorem.

Compilers do not try.

Instead, they have some simple and cheap heuristics that catch common cases.

You **cannot** rely on your compiler to detect every case where you use uninitialized variables.

In this particular case, you are passing `b2` to another class prior to initialization, but only using it to initialize a temporary variable.  That is then used to initialize the variable that was originally initialized.

If that is your simplest case, clang is doing a pretty good job.  Compilers tend to be worse at this when you use a variable as part of its own initialization statement.

Here is an even simpler case:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo()
    : b2((bool const&)b2) // We are using b2 here before it is initialized, but clang doesn't complain
  { }

  bool b2;
};
```

another case:

```
struct Bob {
    bool b;
    operator bool() const{ return b; }
};

class Foo {
public:
  Foo()
    : b2(Bob{b2}) // We are using b2 here before it is initialized, but clang doesn't complain
  { }

  bool b2;
};
```

another

```
Bob bob = {Bob{bob.b}.b};
```

I can go on.

Clang **does not claim** to detect all uninitialized variable uses.  So it failing to detect one is not a "bug".  Rather, getting them to detect another uninitialized case is a new feature.